Should I pass QSettings to main window as a reference or is it safe to copy?
I am not sure if there is some smart pointer magic for settings. This is how I use them now:

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // This is a windows only application, so I hardcoded saving to %APPDATA%/MyApp/settings.ini
    QString appDataPath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
    QString projectAppDataDir = QDir::cleanPath(appDataPath + "/" + APPLICATION_NAME);
    QString iniFilePath = QDir::cleanPath(projectAppDataDir + "/" + "settings.ini");
    // Prepare folder for the settings
    {
        QDir createDir{appDataPath};

        if(!createDir.mkpath(APPLICATION_NAME)) {
            qDebug() << "Failed to create app data directory.";
        }
    }
    QSettings mainSettings(iniFilePath, QSettings::Format::IniFormat);
    // test value to ensure sync() works
    mainSettings.setValue("test", 22);
    qDebug() << "Saving settings into: " << iniFilePath;
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    // pass by ref to main window
    MainWindow w{mainSettings};
    w.show();
    int res = a.exec();
    // sync only of app did not crash
    mainSettings.sync();
    return res;
}

The constructor to main window then looks like this:
MainWindow(QSettings& globalSettings, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

It stores the reference in the main window class, rather than copying it. The question is if that is necessary. The lifetime of the settings is pretty much the lifetime of the application, so it should not be an issue, but I do not like storing references anyway.

Do the MainWindow object need to save a copy of the settings? Is it only used for initialization of the object? If you don't need an actual copy of the object, then storing a reference is fine (assuming a life-time that's longer than the MainWindow object).

I am making a simple application, so I am going to modify the qsettings directly from main window and then expect the sync() call in main() to save the new values. I know that this is not a clean approach, but for simple app I don't want to over engineer setting management. So my question is basically whether if QSettings object is copied, it retains a reference to the origin or if it is a truly a copy, meaning sync() would not work if I stored it by value and not ref.

Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "QSettings object is copied"?  As far as I'm aware QSettings is non-copyable.

That would pretty much answer the question. I feel stupid for not checking that.

No worries :-)  Note that if you are concerned about the lifetime of the QSettings vs that of the MainWindow, you could have MainWindow store a QPointer<QSettings> -- that way you can always check its validity prior to use.
